# Can't find module airtable even though I ran npm install airtable

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, airtable

I am currently trying to use the airtable api for the backend of my website, but when I write (nodejs)

```
var Airtable = require('airtable');
```

and execute the file via `node [filepath]` the command prompt throws an error saying

```
Error: Cannot find module 'airtable'
```

I have already written

```
npm install airtable
```

so the module should be installed, right?

I would expect, with the full code, for it to set up a server on localhost port 3000, but I can't get past the `require()` statement.

package.json (some info omitted):

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "airtable": "^0.7.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "require": "^2.4.20"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize a `package.json` file? Can you see the `node_modules` folder in your directory? Just running `npm install` won't save the package locally unless there is a package.json present in your directory

Comment: Yea that was it. Thank you @dpopp07

Comment: Actually, it's now in the package.json but it still can't find the module... @dpopp07
I included the package above

Comment: Nevermind it works now. The package wasn’t installed in the root directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing an official answer for anyone else with this problem:

To install a Node module to be used in your project, you must first initialize a `package.json` file. This will tell `npm` to create a `node_modules/` folder and install the module in your project directory.

You can initialize that file with the command:

```
$ npm init -y
```

(The `-y` flag tells the command to create the file using default values, otherwise it will promt you for all of the values)

[More documentation on `npm init`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)